# Simple website with a GPL V3 Framework

Tags: licensing, gpl

I write web-based software and simple website ("Home", "Who we are", "Contact").

For a simple website I'm using a covered GPL v3 framework. The user surf the website, send an email, take info, etc. I repeat: simple website, not a Joomla or Wordpress.

1) Will the website be covered with the GPL? I don't modify the framework. I'm using his classes in other classes... (OOP).

2) For the point 1, if yes, do I need to add (e.g. in the footer) name of framework and his link?

3) I must permit download of entire website to study code (nothing that a programmer has interest in)? E.g. placing it in Github?

4) If 2 is NO, how you can "understand" that we use that framework? In effect no php lines are exposed to the browser... You cannot understand that when you push "Send email" the site is calling `$this->send($email)`. If you write me an email "Are you using XXX framework"? I can answer NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three variations of the GPL v3 license that can have different effects towards your website: the regular GPL, LGPL and Affero GPL.

The Affero GPL license gives the clearest situation here: As your website provides the public the possibility to execute the code of the website (by accessing it), you must also provide public access to the code of your website under terms compatible with the Affero GPL license.

Under both the GPL and LGPL, the mere fact that others can execute the code residing on your server does not mean that you are distributing that code. So, if you just host the website without giving a download link for the code (or putting it in a publicly accessible repository), you are not distributing the code and any requirements that a framework or library has on redistribution are moot.

If you *do* provide public access to your code, then the use of a GPL licensed framework most likely means that your code must also be released under the GPL license. The only exception is if the framework uses the LGPL license and is linked into your code as a replaceable library.

---

With regards to naming the framework used in your website, unless it is a requirement in their copyright license, you have no obligation to name the framework, but it can be seen as a gesture of goodwill if you do mention the framework and provide a link to it. Preferably, the link should point at the homepage of the framework.

Comment: I like your answer. The framework has GPL V3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html , so from your answer I understand exactly that I'm not distributing the code. Of course, in projects where I can do, I'll left a link to the frameorks... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are not distributing the framework or any of its code, you're distributing a website of your own creative design (unless ofcourse you didn't actually designed it). As such you do not need a license, let alone conform to anything it has to say.

The GPL accompanying your framework of choice does not cover the contents of your website, nor the design.

As for being required to "state" that you're using a certain framework, I do NOT believe there is any legal basis for this, atleast not as far as a GPL license would be concerned. The GPL only cares about forced reproduction when being modified (or linked to, ew ugh nasty, use BSD license instead).

Disclaimer: I AM NOT A LAWYER. I DISLIKE GPL.

Comment: -1. As the website is a derived work of the framework, the GPL license claims applicability to the code of the website as well as the framework.

Comment: Since there is a seperate license, the AGPL, that specifically mentions the use case of the website, its very safe to say that under the rugular GPL and LGLP this is not the case. As stated. As such, the GPL does not claim applicability to the code of the website. Furthermore, the problem with questions like this is it comes down to interpretation.

Comment: The difference between AGPL and regular GPL is whether or not a website is considered distribution of the code that makes up the website. This does not affect in any way that, if you distribute the source for your product, the GPL claims applicability if your source uses a GPL licensed library or framework.

Comment: Exactly. So if he's publishing nothing but the website, how is the frameworks code being redistributed (regardless from if it was modified or not)? I believe we're saying exactly the same thing? The GPL does not apply to his website, it applies to the framework.